# Plot groupby percentage dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I didn't  find a complete answer to what i want to do:

I have a dataframe. I want to group by user and their answers to a survey, sum all of their good answers/total of their answers, display it in % and plot the result.

I have an answer column which contains : 1,0 or -1. I want to filter it in order to exclude -1.

Here is what i did so far :

```
df_sample.groupby('user').filter(lambda x : x['answer'].mean() >-1)
```

or :

```
a = df_sample.loc[df_sample['answer']!=-1,['user','answer']]
b = a.groupby(['user','answer']).agg({'answer' : 'sum'})
```

See it's uncomplete. Thank you for any suggestion that you may have.

Comment: To get a proportion change `.agg({'answer' : 'sum'})` to `.agg({'answer' : 'mean'})`.  If I understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with some sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), size=n),
                   'answer': np.random.choice([1, 0, -1], size=n)})
```

`df.head()`:

```
  user  answer
0    D       1
1    C       0
2    D      -1
3    B       1
4    C       1
```

---

#### Option 1

Filter out the `-1` values and use named aggregation to get the "good answers" and "total answers":

```
plot_df = df[df['answer'].ne(-1)].groupby('user').aggregate(
    good_answer=('answer', 'sum'),
    total_answer=('answer', 'size')
)
```

`plot_df`:

```
      good_answer  total_answer
user                           
A               9            15
B              11            20
C              15            19
D               7            14
```

Use division and multiplication to get percentage:

```
plot_df['pct'] = (plot_df['good_answer'] / plot_df['total_answer'] * 100)
```

`plot_df`:

```
      good_answer  total_answer        pct
user                                      
A               9            15  60.000000
B              11            20  55.000000
C              15            19  78.947368
D               7            14  50.000000
```

Then this can be plotted with [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot):

```
ax = plot_df.plot(
    y='pct', kind='bar', rot=0,
    title='Percentage of Good Answers',
    ylim=[0, 100],
    label='Percent Good'
)

# Add Labels on Top of Bars
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%.2f%%')

plt.show()
```

---

#### Option 2

If *just* the percentage is needed [`groupby mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-mean) can be used to get to the resulting plot directly after filtering out the `-1`s:

```
plot_df = df[df['answer'].ne(-1)].groupby('user')['answer'].mean().mul(100)

ax = plot_df.plot(
    kind='bar', rot=0,
    title='Percentage of Good Answers',
    ylim=[0, 100],
    label='Percent Good'
)
# Add Labels on Top of Bars
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%.2f%%')

plt.show()
```

`plot_df`:

```
         answer
user           
A     60.000000
B     55.000000
C     78.947368
D     50.000000
```

---

Both options Produce:

[image: plot]

---

All together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': np.random.choice(list("ABCD"), size=n),
                   'answer': np.random.choice([1, 0, -1], size=n)})

plot_df = df[df['answer'].ne(-1)].groupby('user').aggregate(
    good_answer=('answer', 'sum'),
    total_answer=('answer', 'size')
)
plot_df['pct'] = (plot_df['good_answer'] / plot_df['total_answer'] * 100)

ax = plot_df.plot(
    y='pct', kind='bar', rot=0,
    title='Percentage of Good Answers',
    ylim=[0, 100],
    label='Percent Good'
)

# Add Labels on Top of Bars
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%.2f%%')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample solution assuming you want to calculate percentage based on filtered dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,2,size=(10, 1)), columns=['answer'])
df_sample['user'] = [i for i in 'a b c d e f a b c d'.split(' ')]
df_filtered = df_sample[df_sample.answer>-1]


print(df_filtered.groupby('user').agg({'answer' : lambda x: x.sum()/len(df_filtered)*100}))
```